# Getting character that is offset from another

Tags: ruby

I want to do like 'a' + 2 = 'c', so I wrote:

```
('a'.ord + 2).chr
```

And yes I get 'c'.

But it looks so redundant. Is there any better straight way to do it? Using 1.9.3

Comment: I don't think ["redundant"](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=redundant) is the right word here; nothing is being repeated or unnecessary. Perhaps you feel that it's too "verbose" or "roundabout".

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this functionality? Perhaps if you described what you were trying to achieve in the end (why do you have integers representing character offsets) we could better help you.

Comment: Yeah it is roundabout. String is an array of bytes anyway so why should we convert it to integer, and back to string? If I look into Rubinius kernel code, there is definition of string as bytearray, maybe I can do something but in official I don't know what to do.

Comment: It was good in 1.8. In 1.8, 'aaa'[0] will just return 97. I have no idea why they changed it.

Comment: You can always use `"hello world".bytes.map{ |n| n+3 }.pack("c*") #=> "khoor#zruog"`...assuming that you have only single-byte string encoding.

Comment: "They" changed it because assuming that one character == one byte is a very limited, ASCII-centric world view that does not account for the various multi-byte string encodings, such as UTF-8 where `"é".length != "é".bytes.to_a.length`

Comment: Well they can use codepoint for return value instead of byte. It is integer(or maybe I should just say a number) anyway. `"é".codepoint` should be there

Comment: Well, there is [`String#codepoints`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-codepoints); again, a string of length 1 is not the same as a character.

Comment: Yes a string of length 1 is not the same as a ascii char, but it is the same as a code point. String#codepoints returns an enumerator instead of an array which I can access by the index.

Comment: I mean that a string is an instance of class String, regardless of length. You can't add or remove methods based on instance value. `"ab".codepoint` makes no sense, and thus `"a".codepoint` should not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a universally 'better' way to do it (given some random definition of 'better'; mine may not match yours). That's my real answer: **do what you are doing**.

For fun, however, you could do this *inefficient* monkeypatch that does not step through integer land:

```
class String
  alias_method :__succ,:succ
  def succ(steps=nil)
    steps ? dup.tap{ |c| steps.times{ c.succ! } } : __succ
  end
end

puts "a".succ(2) #=> "c"
```

However, this has the possibly-undesirable side-effect:

```
p [24,25,26,27].map{ |s| "a".succ(s) }
#=> ["y", "z", "aa", "ab"]
```

---

If you need to offset many ASCII characters by the same offset:

```
p "hello".bytes.map{ |c| c+3 }.pack( "c*" ) #=> "khoor"
```

---

If you need to calculate many offsets from a single character (like "a") ASCII characters by the same offset:

```
A = "a".ord
p [1,2,3,7,20,25].map{ |n| A+n }.pack( "c*" ) #=> "bcdhuz"
```

---

If you need to calculate many offsets from a variety of characters:

```
chars   = "hello"
offsets = [15,10,6,0,-11]
puts chars.bytes.zip(offsets).map{|a,b| a+b }.pack( "c*" )
#=> "world"
```

Comment: Yeah repetitive `succ` does the job, but it is not as efficient as directly plus a certain value I suppose. The last one deals with a bunch of chars and is very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Well a *really, really bad* way to do it would be like this:

```
class String

  alias_method :original_plus, :+

  def +(other)
    if self.length == 1 and other.is_a?(Fixnum)
      (self.ord + other).chr
    else
      original_plus(other)
    end
  end

end

puts 'a' + 2
=> c
```

Comment: Yeah I have this in my own lib. But it still use char->int->char. Can we just do char+int directly like C?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a Char class in Ruby, only String. That's why you need the `self.length == 1` check...

Comment: I can't tell if I should -1 this. On the one hand, it is a _really_ bad idea. On the other hand, you say that in your answer.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps then you should +1 it? ;-)

Comment: I don't know if I should accept the answer because you just wraps my code up in a method and override the original operator. Internally it still does the same thing: string->integer->string

Comment: Well, if it helps: "No, there is no neat way to do this in Ruby. I wouldn't recommend opening up `String` in the way I have here, but encapsulating it in a method is the best way to make your approach better if you need to do it a lot".